# Baum Welch algorithm for Semi-Continuous (Tied-Mixture) Hidden Markov Model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch

I'm currently implementing Baum-Welch algorithm for Semi-Continuous Hidden Markov Model (SCHMM) as described in Huang, Xuedong. *Semi-continuous hidden Markov models for speech recognition*, 1989, pages 96-97. In SCHMM one assumes that emission probability given a state follows a mixture of gaussian pdfs that are shared among all states and the only difference lies in mixture coefficients
\begin{align}
b_j(x_t) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^M w_{jk} \mathcal{N}(x_t, \mu_k, \Sigma_k)
\end{align}

```
numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

def gmm_density(obs, w, mu, sd):
    gauss_mixt = w*norm.pdf(obs, mu, sd)
    return gauss_mixt

def initial_params(N, M, X):
    w = np.random.random(M*N).reshape(N, M)
    w = w/np.sum(w, axis = 1).reshape(-1,1)
    
    mu = np.random.uniform(min(X)*2, max(X)*2, M)
    
    sigma = np.random.uniform(1, 20, M)
    
    A = np.random.rand(N, N)
    A /= A.sum(axis = 1)[:,None]
    
    pi = np.random.random(N)
    pi /= pi.sum()
    
    return list([pi, A, w, mu, sigma])

# Forward variable with scaling
def alpha_vec(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma):

    scaling_factor = np.ones(len(obs))
    alpha_matrix = np.zeros((len(states), len(obs)))
    
    # for t = 0
    
    alpha_matrix[:,0] = pi*np.sum(gmm_density(obs[0], w, mu, sigma), axis = 1)
    scaling_factor[0] = 1/np.sum(alpha_matrix[:,0], axis = 0)
    alpha_matrix[:,0] *= scaling_factor[0]
    
    # for t == 1:T
    for t in range(1, len(obs)):
        alpha_matrix[:,t] = np.matmul(alpha_matrix[:,t-1], A)*np.sum(gmm_density(obs[t], w, mu, sigma), axis = 1)
        scaling_factor[t] = 1/np.sum(alpha_matrix[:,t], axis = 0)
        alpha_matrix[:,t] *= scaling_factor[t]

    return alpha_matrix, scaling_factor

# Backward variable with scaling 
def beta_vec(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma, ct):
    
    # for t = T
    beta_matrix = np.zeros((len(states), len(obs)))
    beta_matrix[:,len(obs)-1] = np.ones(len(states))
    beta_matrix[:,len(obs)-1] = beta_matrix[:,len(obs)-1]*ct[len(obs)-1]

    # for t = (T-1):1
    for t in reversed(range(0,len(obs)-1)):
        beta_matrix[:,t] = A @ (beta_matrix[:,t+1] * np.sum(gmm_density(obs[t+1], w, mu, sigma), axis = 1))
        beta_matrix[:,t] = beta_matrix[:,t]*ct[t]
    return beta_matrix

def chi(obs, alpha, beta, A, w, mu, sigma):
    # i, j, k, t
    chi_probs = np.zeros((len(states), len(states), M, len(obs)-1))
    for t in range(len(obs)-1):
        for k in range(M):
            chi_probs[:,:,k,t] = alpha[:,t].reshape(-1,1) * np.ones((N, N)) * A * gmm_density(obs[t+1], w, mu, sigma)[:,k].T * np.ones((N, N)) * (beta[:,t+1] * np.ones((N, N)))    
    return chi_probs


N = 3
M = 5

x1 = np.random.randn(100, 1)
x2 = 12 + np.random.randn(40, 1)
x3 = -1 + np.random.randn(60, 1)
x4 = 3 + np.random.randn(60, 1)
x5 = 7.5 + np.random.randn(40, 1)

X = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5))

iters = 100

start_params = initial_params(N, M, X)
pi_r = start_params[0]
A_r = start_params[1]
w_r = start_params[2]
mu_r = start_params[3]
sigma_r = start_params[4]
states = list(range(0,N))

mu_track = np.zeros((M, iters+1))
pi_track = np.zeros((N, iters+1))
A_track = np.zeros((N, N, iters+1))
sigma_track = np.zeros((M, iters+1))
w_track = np.zeros((N, M, iters+1))
llhood_r = np.zeros((iters+1))

mu_track[:, 0] = mu_r
sigma_track[:, 0] = sigma_r
A_track[:,:, 0] = A_r
w_track[:,:, 0] = w_r
pi_track[:, 0] = pi_r


for it in range(1, iters):
    print("Iteration: ", it)
    print("Initial probs: ", np.round(pi_r, 4), "with sum", np.round(np.sum(pi_r), 4))
    print("Trans mat: \n", np.round(A_r, 4), "\nwith row sums", np.round(np.sum(A_r, axis = 1), 4) )
    print("Weights: \n", np.round(w_r, 4), "\nwith sums", np.round(np.sum(w_r, axis = 1), 4))
    print("Means: ", np.round(mu_r, 4))
    print("Sigmas: ", np.round(sigma_r, 4), "\n")
    
    a, ct = alpha_vec(X, states, A_r, pi_r, w_r, mu_r, sigma_r)
    llhood_r[it-1] = np.log(np.sum(a[:,len(X)-1])) - np.sum(np.log(ct))
    print("Log-likelihood: ", np.round(llhood_r[it-1], 4), "\n\n")
    b = beta_vec(X, states, A_r, pi_r, w_r, mu_r, sigma_r, ct)
    chi_mat = chi(X, a, b, A_r, w_r, mu_r, sigma_r)
    
    
    if (it > 0):
        if (np.abs(llhood_r[it-1] - llhood_r[it-2]) < 0.001):
            iters = it
            break


    gamma_gen = np.sum(chi_mat, axis = 2)
    gamma_toT = np.sum(gamma_gen, axis = 1)
    gammaT = ((a[:,len(X)-1]*b[:,len(X)-1])/ct[len(ct)-1]).reshape(-1,1)
    gamma = np.hstack((gamma_toT, gammaT))
    ksi_gen0 = (pi_r*b[:,0]).reshape(-1,1) * gmm_density(X[0], w_r, mu_r, sigma_r)
    ksi_gen_rest = np.sum(chi_mat, axis = 0)[:,:,0:len(X)]
    ksi_gen = np.dstack((ksi_gen0, ksi_gen_rest))
    ksi = np.sum(ksi_gen, axis = 0)

    ### Pi
    pi_r = gamma[:,0]
    
    ### A
    A_r = np.sum(gamma_gen, axis = 2)/np.sum(gamma[:,0:len(X)-1], axis = 1).reshape(-1,1)
    
    ### W
    w_r = np.sum(ksi_gen, axis = 2)/(np.sum(gamma, axis = 1).reshape(-1,1))
    
    ### Mu 
    mu_r = np.sum(ksi*(X.T), axis = 1)/np.sum(ksi, axis = 1)  
    
    ### Sigma
    sigma_r = np.sum((ksi*((X-mu_r)*(X-mu_r)).T) , axis = 1)/np.sum(ksi, axis = 1)  

    if pd.isna(mu_r).any():
        iters = it
        break
    if pd.isna(sigma_r).any():
        iters = it
        break
    
        
    mu_track[:, it] = mu_r
    sigma_track[:, it] = sigma_r
    A_track[:,:, it] = A_r
    w_track[:,:, it] = w_r
    pi_track[:, it] = pi_r
    
        
a, ct = alpha_vec(X, states, A_r, pi_r, w_r, mu_r, sigma_r)
llhood_r[iters] = np.log(np.sum(a[:,len(X)-1])) - np.sum(np.log(ct))
```

However, when I track `llhood_r` it is not always nondecreasing, even if there are no singularities while estimating $\Sigma$ and $\mu$. Honestly, I'm completely out of ideas here.

**EDIT:** when I set $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ to some constant values and don't reestimate these parameters, then log-likelihood function is perfectly non-decreasing. I have double-checked formuals for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, but everything is fine. **However**, I found a concerning behaviour. Let's assume that I want to estimate mixture parameters for a trimodal distribution, say $0.25\mathcal{N}(-10, 1) + 0.5\mathcal{N}(0, 1) + 0.25\mathcal{N}(10, 1)$. What I end up getting with reestimation formulas is something like  $c_{1}\mathcal{N}(0, 25) + c_{2}\mathcal{N}(0, 25) + c_{3}\mathcal{N}(0, 25)$, so a bell curve that "covers" the true distribution. It somehow makes sense, but has little to no use for my problem.